# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded for large schemas during NestJS bootstrap

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using nestjs and graphQL for backend.

When bootstraping the nextjs backend I am encountering the error :

```
        RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at LazyMetadataStorageHost.load (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/schema-builder/storages/lazy-metadata.storage.js:33:49)
    at GraphQLSchemaFactory.create (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/schema-builder/graphql-schema.factory.js:37:53)
    at GraphQLSchemaBuilder.generateSchema (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql-schema.builder.js:36:52)
    at GraphQLSchemaBuilder.build (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql-schema.builder.js:23:31)
    at GraphQLFactory.mergeWithSchema (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql.factory.js:29:69)
    at ApolloDriver.start (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/apollo/dist/drivers/apollo.driver.js:19:51)
    at GraphQLModule.onModuleInit (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql.module.js:104:36)
    at callModuleInitHook (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:51:9)
    at NestApplication.callInitHook (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:178:13)
    at NestApplication.init (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:96:9)
    at NestApplication.listen (/home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:155:33)
    at bootstrap (/home/ubuntu/backend_deploy/dev/apps/commerce/src/main.ts:58:5)
[Nest] 12630  - 11/17/2022, 8:39:53 PM   ERROR ⚠️ error ⚠️: 
[Nest] 12630  - 11/17/2022, 8:39:53 PM   ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  prisma:client:libraryEngine:loader  Searching for Query Engine Library in /home/ubuntu/backend_deploy/dev/node_modules/.prisma/client +0ms
  prisma:client:libraryEngine:loader  loadEngine using /home/ubuntu/backend/dev/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.
```

The details of my application flow are summarized below :
main.ts file

```
    async function bootstrap() {
      try {
        const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule,{ cors: {
            credentials: true,
            origin: [
              'http://localhost:3005',
              'http://localhost:4200',
              :
            ],
          },})
    
        app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
        app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
        app.useGlobalPipes(
          new ValidationPipe({
            transform: true,
            always: true, },
           
            exceptionFactory: (errors) => {
              Logger.error(errors)
              const formatted = errors.map((error) => errorMap(error))
    
              return new BadRequestException(formatted)
            },
          }),
        )
    
        const globalPrefix = 'api'
        app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix)
        const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
        await app.listen(port, () => {
          Logger.log(` Application is running on: http://localhost:${port}/${globalPrefix}`)
          Logger.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port + '/graphql')
          // Logger.log(`Running in ${config.get('environment')} mode`)
        })
      } catch (err) {
        // add some error logging mechanism
        Logger.error('⚠️ error ⚠️: ', err)
      }
    }

bootstrap()
```

In my app.module I am importing multiple modules

```
import { DataModule, DataService } from '@mytest/data'
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo'
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'
import { APP_FILTER, APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core'
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql'
import { AcceptLanguageResolver, I18nJsonLoader, I18nModule, QueryResolver } from 'nestjs-i18n'
import { AddModule } from './adds/adds.module'
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module'
import { CommonModule } from './common/common.module'
:
:

//Loading the schema from GraphQL generated file :
  GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      autoSchemaFile: true, // join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      debug: false,
      playground: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true,
      context: (ctx) => ctx,
      introspection: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true,
      cors: {
        credentials: true,
        origin: [
          'http://localhost:3005',
          'http://localhost:4200',
    :
        ],
      },
    }),
```

SChema generation

```
generator nestgraphql { 
provider = "prisma-nestjs-graphql" 
output = "../src/data/generated/" 
// reExport = "All" 
// combineScalarFilters = true 
noAtomicOperations = true 
emitSingle = false 
purgeOutput = true }
```

The issue seems to be similar to [git issue](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/pull/2402) - *When bootstrapping a gql application, having many schemas results in a very large memory footprint.
For our project with 200 schemas, we couldn't run the server because it consumed past 8GB memory and died on OOM*.

Anyone faced the issue when using large schemas. Is there any workaround/suggestions when using large schemas and prisma generated files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using PrismaClientExtensions preview feature? The reason I ask is that there is a related GitHub Issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/16600

Comment: We are only using transactions from preview => generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}

Comment: Ok, so that might not be related. Is your project open source? If yes, can you share the link? trying to reproduce the issue locally would be helpful to find a fix.